# Why does the FormClosing event produce a deadlock in a synchronized thread job using Monitors?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, deadlock

This is a bit difficult to explain. I have a thread instantiated within a WindowsForm, the thread is not a priority and does its job if nobody has taken the resource exclusively using Monitor.TryEnter.

But when closing the form I use the FormClosing event to stop the processing, save the processed data before closing, etc. When trying to take the resource with another Monitor.Enter .. the block is produced.

But the funny thing is that in the following way it works!!. Using a new/secondary thread or task to block the internal thread and perform the final job of save buffering.

"Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:"

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly object _syncRoot = new object();
        private volatile bool _working = false;

        readonly Label lblInfo = new Label();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SuspendLayout();

            lblInfo.Text = "...";
            lblInfo.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            Controls.Add(lblInfo);

            CheckBox chkBox = new CheckBox();
            chkBox.Text = "Use Task inside FormClosing";
            chkBox.AutoSize = true;
            chkBox.Location = new Point(Width / 2 - chkBox.Width / 2, Height / 2 + chkBox.Height);
            chkBox.Click += ChkBox_Click; ;
            Controls.Add(chkBox);

            ResumeLayout(false);

            FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
        }

        private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenS;
        private bool _flUseThread = false;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _cancellationTokenS = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken token = _cancellationTokenS.Token;

            _working = true;
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (_working)
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;

                    processData(DateTime.Now);
                }
            }, token);
        }

        private void ChkBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _flUseThread = ((CheckBox)sender).Checked;
        }

        private bool _alreadySafedClose = false;

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_flUseThread)
            {
                if (_alreadySafedClose) return;

                if (MessageBox.Show(this,
                        "Do you really want to cancel?", "Question:",
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true; // Avoid close form.
                    Enabled = false; // Avoid interact with form.

                    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        bool lockWasTaken = false;
                        try
                        {
                            _working = false;

                            // Lock other thread.
                            Monitor.Enter(_syncRoot, ref lockWasTaken);

                            _cancellationTokenS.Cancel();

                            saveBufferResults();

                            MessageBox.Show("OK with Thread");

                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            // ignored
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            // Release lock other thread if already locked.
                            if (lockWasTaken)
                                Monitor.Exit(_syncRoot);

                            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                _alreadySafedClose = true;
                                Close(); //Finally Close.
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                    e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show(this,
                        "Do you really want to cancel?", "Question:",
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    bool lockWasTaken = false;
                    try
                    {
                        _working = false;

                        _cancellationTokenS.Cancel();

                        // Lock other thread avoid continue processing.
                        Monitor.Enter(_syncRoot, ref lockWasTaken); // <------ here it stays blocked!!

                        saveBufferResults();

                        MessageBox.Show("OK");
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("<DEBUG> The data could not be processed.!");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        // Release lock other thread if already locked.
                        if (lockWasTaken)
                            Monitor.Exit(_syncRoot);
                    }
                }
                else
                    e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

        private void processData(DateTime data)
        {
            //flag to reduce locks..
            if (!_working) return;

            if (Monitor.TryEnter(_syncRoot))
            {
                try
                {
                    //To escape quickly
                    if (_working)
                        innerProcessFrame(data);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("<DEBUG> The data could not be processed.!");
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(_syncRoot);
                }
            }
        }

        private ulong _dataCounter = 0;

        private void innerProcessFrame(DateTime data)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lblInfo.Text = data.Millisecond + " " + _dataCounter;
            });
            _dataCounter++;
        }

        private void saveBufferResults()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe that FormClosing is breaking the synchronization context or blocking the thread of work and
therefore in the event of the thread of work it never reaches the line where it releases the resource
using Monitor.Exit, in the processData(...) method:

My question is why does this happen only when closing the form within the FormClosing event?, because
if I put a button on the form and put the same blocking code everything stops correctly there is no DeadLock, and why does it work creating a secondary thread to do the final work when closing the form ?, and finally if someone knows a better or correct way to solve it.

Comment: The culprit is probably the Invoke call. It will block until the main thread is available to process the call, but the main thread may be waiting for the monitor. So it's a deadlock. You can test this theory by using BeginInvoke instead of Invoke so that it will not block.

Comment: @JohnWu Interesting approach, it may be a solution but I would have to monitor the data with some delay since it would be an asynchronous visualization, the application is much more intensive than the example, and visualizes many more data. I will try to change all the Invoke by BeginInvoke whenever possible, thanks for the solution.

Comment: One more question, how could something be implemented that is not BeginInvoke / Asynchronous ?, I say for the case in which I need to make something be disabled as quickly as possible before any user can touch it. Maybe this solution forces me to put more blocking controls and state variables.

Comment: Personally I would set up a timer with an event that displays the data you want based on a set of variables. The worker thread would just set the variables and let the timer worry about getting them displayed. That way you never need to have a task on the main thread that also blocks. Another option is to use SemaphoreSlim instead of Monitor; it'll allow you to wait for the lock asynchronously. BTW you're not really "supposed" to use BeginInvoke without EndInvoke (I was just suggesting that for testing).